# What unusual effects work with the slider?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It seems that only a select set of effects work with the slider, because whenever I try to adjust my Time Warp Unusual hat, it won't budge one bit.  Yet, when I try to adjust a Nuts n Bolts Unusual hat, it seems to move fine.

Is this a bug on my part? Or is there a predetermined list of effects that work with the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [December 20, 2013](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/December_20,_2013_Patch) patch:

> **Cosmetics**
>
> - "Head" and "Misc" slots for player loadouts have been converted to Cosmetic slots. All items that were previously Head- or
>     Misc-slot-specific can now be equipped in any Cosmetic slot.
> - **Unusual effect positioning can now be adjusted for all Cosmetic-slot items**
> - Unusual Circling Effects have been given a new origin
> - Unusual effects for all Cosmetic-slot items are now visible in the loadout panel and character HUD
> - Fixed the Wiki Cap clipping with the Demoman's head

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any solid data to back my assertion up, but I'm fairly certain that only orbiting effects are affected by the slider. I can confirm that burning flames unusuals don't budge though.

Comment: I know Stormy Storm also works with the slider.